# Microsoft Windows Server SQL Agent not starting on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, sql-server, windows-server-2012

I have a small issue starting SQL Agent on a Windows Server 2012 machine deployed on Amazon EC2. Because we forgot the log-in password, we had to follow [this procedure](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-passwords.html#ResettingAdminPassword). After restarting the server, we cannot start SQL Server and get the following stack trace:

Unable to start service SQLSERVERAGENT on server WIN-E7I6SUJ7I1G. (mscorlib)

---

Program Location:

Server stack trace:

```
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.Service.Start()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed, MessageData& msgData)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ServiceActionHandler.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ServiceControlProgress.ActionCompletedHandler(IAsyncResult result)

===================================

Service Request Timeout (ObjectExplorer)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.Service.CheckServiceActionReturnValueSuccess(UInt32 returnValue)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.Service.Start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try The following:

1. Run services.msc.
2. Find the MSSQLSERVER Service. Right click and open
   properties.
3. Check what service account it is running under (usually
   NTAUTHORITY\SYSTEM, NTAUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE or NTAUTHORITY\NETWORK
   SERIVICE unless you have it running under a different user account
   for security purposes).

As far as I know if you post here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=113300 it might be helpful also.

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, I placed both SQL Server and Agent Accounts to Local System and still get an error when I start the server agent saying "The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion."

Answer (score 0):

Check the service logs, or the windows event log for errors and check them first before posting, if you cant figure out after checking those events, come back